# Como manter a url fixa?

Tags: php, url-rewrite

Estou utilizando o `mod_rewrite` para fazer reescrita da url, mas gostaria de deixa-la fixa, exemplo:

```
www.meusite.com.br/index.html
www.meusite.com.br/produtos.html
www.meusite.com.br/contato.html

Ficar apenas:
www.meusite.com.br
```

Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer, mais em todas elas vc vai ter que ter ou a pagina ou o parametro na url... E outra se é um site que vc está fazendo e deseja que o google faça a indexação não recomento utilizar apenas 1 url

Comment: @JhonatanSimões, não se trata de um site, é um sistema, por isto não é interessante a indexação, Você poderia colocar uma resposta com as formas de resolver este problema, pros e contras deles serão bem vindos também.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria guardar e criar a logica na sessão essas informações, mas vou esperar uma reposta de alguem com experiência. Favoritei aqui, boa a pergunta

Comment: Acho então que modo rewrite não é a solução. Vc pode usar ajax para o carregamento das paginas não alterando a url pois não há redirecionamento. Como minha resposta foge da pergunta, se quiser posso postar o código...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @Jhonatan Simões disse, você pode utilizar JavaScript pra isso. Você deve colocar uma div, que será o corpo todo da página principal e utilizar o load do jQuery. No Google tem uma infinidade de exemplos, mas pra facilitar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011191/help-with-jquery-load.

Para o sistema saber qual página ele deve carregar, você tem que passar a url da página por parâmetro. Use o método POST, já que você quer deixar a barra de endereços "limpa".

Se você não quiser toda essa tranqueira, usa algumas manhas do .htaccess. Não vai ficar totalmente como você quer, mas vai ajudar bastante.

Outra dica é: ao invés de passar parâmetros por GET (vai ficar feio na url) e POST (vai dar problema se dar F5 ou volta a página), passa as informações necessárias por variáveis de sessão, cookies ou até input hidden. Com isso, você consegue deixar a url assim: www.meusite.com.br/pagina.

Comment: Lembrando sempre que ao usar JavaScript você fica dependendo da colaboração do usuário, já que este pode ser facilmente desativado no navegador.

Comment: Concordo. Não gosto muito de fazer esse tipo de coisa. Se fosse eu, o sistema utilizaria JavaScript só pra validações de formulários e requisições no banco de dados sem ter que recarregar a página. Porque se o usuário der um F5 ou voltar a página, já começa a ficar chato de usar.

Comment: Acredito então que se essa for a unica solução possivel ela não será viavel para mim, `+1`

Comment: Acho que a melhor maneira ainda continua sendo via ajax, assim vc navegaria pelas páginas sem recarregar e trocar de url.

Comment: Se você não quiser toda essa tranqueira, usa algumas manhas do .htaccess. Não vai ficar totalmente como você quer, mas vai ajudar bastante. Outra dica é: ao invés de passar parâmetros por GET (vai ficar feio na url) e POST (vai dar problema se dar F5 ou volta a página), passa as informações necessárias por variáveis de sessão, cookies ou até input hidden. Com isso, você consegue deixar a url assim: www.meusite.com.br/pagina.

Comment: Porém, se você ainda for usar o ajax para load das páginas, talvez não consiga trabalhar o SEO do site, onde dificultaria que os mecanismos de busca achem seu site... tem esse porém.

Comment: @AndréBaill Sobre as questões de SEO foram explicadas nos comentários da pergunta